# Which scopes are needed to get a refresh token for O365 SMTP?

Tags: oauth, smtp, office365, phpmailer

We use in our company email addresses for each employee and for 3 departments (service, support and reports) - for example `<employee_name>@<company_name>.de` or `support@<company_name>.de` ("<..._name>" is just a placholder for posting here). Our programs use PHPMailer for sending Emails from the 3 departments via SMTP (Host: `smtp.office365.com`), that means the PHPMailer is called by programs/scripts that are started by the Microsoft Task Scheduler on a computer where none of our Microsoft-Users is logged in. Now we want to switch from Basic SMTP Auth to Oauth2. So we registered in the main tenant (`<boss_name>@<company_name>.de`) in the azure portal a web app "PHPMailer".

To get a refresh token i have to open the file `get_oauth_token.php`, which is included in PHPMailer, in a brwoser. In that file the scope for Microsoft is `['wl.imap', 'wl.offline_access']`. Unfortunately i can't find the information, if that is just a default or example scope and i have to change it for my needs (SMTP), or if it has to be allways that scope independent for what i need the token. Furthermore i can't informations about how to name the scope in that file (for example `offline_access` vs. `wl.offline_access`) and what that `wl.` means.

In the azure portal we've set the application permissions `Mail.Send` and `User.Read`. The last one was already there.

I've read in the past weeks countless tutorials from Microsoft, PHPMailer and others, and forums like stackoverflow. But nowhere i could find the necessary information.

## Examples:

### Microsoft

[Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

[How to set up a multifunction device or application to send email using Microsoft 365 or Office 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365)

[Permissions and consent in the Microsoft identity platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types)

### PHPMailer

[Using Gmail with XOAUTH2](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2) (unfortunately no explanation for Microsoft)

[Basic Usage](https://oauth2-client.thephpleague.com/usage/) of the OAuth 2.0 Client from the PHP League

[Microsoft Provider for OAuth 2.0 Client](https://github.com/stevenmaguire/oauth2-microsoft) Microsoft OAuth 2.0 support for PHPMailer from Steven Maguire

---

So, which scope i need for O365 SMTP and how i have to name it in the file `get_oauth_token.php`?

(if you need more informations, please tell me...)

---

## Update:

### PHPMailer

Thanks to @greew i found a well made explanation with helpfull screenshots for delegated permissions:

[Microsoft Azure and XOAUTH2 setup guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-and-XOAUTH2-setup-guide)

Unfortunately it doesn't help for my case with application permissions, because it is made for the case, that the Microsoft user is logged in on the compauter where PHPMailer is working.

Comment: Maybe this tutorial (although not for PHP) could help you: https://www.codewrecks.com/post/security/accessing-office-365-imap-with-oauth2/, at least when it comes to setting up the Azure side.
Among other things, it declares that you should have these 4 rights set up, when registering the application in the Azure: `email`, `offline_access`, `User.Read`, `IMAP.AccessAsUser.All`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we don't use IMAP. We use SMTP, but i will check the link although...

Answer (score 1):

I will help you the best I can based on your problem.

As long as you have the login credentials it doenst matter where to run the steps below to get all the necessary info. From what I can tell that your company doesn't have a whitelist.

Below will clarify some things and setup. The most important step is to have a redirect URL that matches your url like http://localhost/get_oauth_token.php doesn't really matter what you call it as long as it is the same as in Azure. Best practice is to use a domain. After you have acquired the token it doesn't matter where you run your mailing then.

**1.** composer require greew/oauth2-azure-provider

**2.** [tutorial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Microsoft-Azure-and-XOAUTH2-setup-guide)

**3.** [get_oauth_token.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/2793/files#diff-cce8aea41bef9eae7567cdfd570c84883d0e960f2951c505d0e7e02885ef38ef) save it, and run it. Provide ClientId, ClientSecret, TenantID from tutorial. Login with your emailadres in you tenant. It will redirect to login page from microsoft, put in your emailadres en password. It wil create a token. Copy paste the token.

**4.** [test mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/pull/2793/files#diff-28e122e27586817e889514dd346f49b26de94bb1005be022dfcc73d5e3380f95) Save it. Put in email, ClientId, ClientSecret, TenantID, and the token.

Change addAddress to what you want it to be.
If all goes well you it will send a test email.

One thing to keep in mind. For every emailadres in your tenent you need to run get_oauth_token.php and login with the specific emailadres to get a token. Every emailadres has a unique token! Also keep in mind that there is a key timeout set by yourself. So don't make the expiration to short. If it expires, than this will need to start over again with get_oauth_token.php.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to send emails with these steps through a program on a computer where no windows user is logged in?

Comment: The whole point of the steps is to get a token. If you like; you can run it on your own PC with wamp, php 7.3> also dont forget to install composer on the PC and composer require phpmailer/phpmailer in www. Afterwords it doesn't matter where you run it. viel spaß

Comment: You didn't answer my question. I ask it because Microsoft itself says, that it only supports the case, that the user is logged in on that computer...

Comment: So you are using SMTP AUTH, with windows scheduler right? its just the same with OAUTH. Only difference is that you need a token one time to get it working just like SMTP AUTH.

Comment: I know, that i need a token. And i can send an E-Mail from that server without beeing logged in, but only from one email address. But your hint, that i need to get a token for every email address, is very helpful- I will try that...